# What is the integral of $\int \left(1-\frac{1}{x} \right)e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} dx$

Tags: integration

I've tried substitution $u = \frac{1}{x} \implies du = -\frac{1}{x^2}dx \implies dx = -x^2du$ which leads me to the integral $$\int \left( 1-u\right)e^{1+u} \cdot \frac{-1}{u^2} du$$ $$=\int \frac{-e^{1+u}}{u^2} du + \int \frac{e^{1+u}}{u} du $$
But I dont see how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative: Notice that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) =-\frac{1}{x^2}$. We have
\begin{align*}
\int e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} - \frac{1}{x} \cdot e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} dx &= \int  e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} + x \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{x^2} \right) e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}dx \\
&= \int \frac{dx}{dx} \cdot e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} + x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left( e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} \right)dx \\
&= \int \frac{d}{dx} \left(xe^{1+\frac{1}{x}} \right) dx \\
&= xe^{1+\frac{1}{x}}  + C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts:

$$-\int \frac{e^{1+u}}{u^2} \, du = \frac{e^{1+u}}u - \int \frac{e^{1+u}}u \, du$$

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the integral into 2 and performing integration by parts on the first integral yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} d x 
= & \int e^{1+\frac{1}{x}} d x-\int \frac{e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x} d x \\
= & x e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\int x e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\int \frac{e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x} d x \\
= & x e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\int \frac{e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x} d x-\int \frac{e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x} d x \\
= & x e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}+C 
\end{aligned}
$$